# Access error You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'User'

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm working with access and I want to upload a photo for an existing user. I get this error "You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'User'". I saw here on the site that the problem was entering the wrong value in the foreign key but it isn't the case here.
The Tables:
[image]

The photo variable isn't connected to the table Photo because I need the id of the photo, so I must insert it before. then i get
the id of the photo from the username and saving the photo as the id+type - like 3.jpg - and then updating the user table.
But Even before all of this I still cant insert a single photo.

Answer (score 0):

> The photo variable isn't connected to the table Photo because I need
>   the id of the photo

I don't know what that means, but - as the error message tells you - you need an existing username for the Photo table before you can insert a photo record.

Comment: Do you mean existing username in the User Table? Because how can i have it in the Photo table before i insert it? For example I have a user named steve and he uploaded a picture so I insert the photo with the username steve.And what i meant isn't relate to the problem so it's doesn't matter.